# Under what conditions on a continuous function $f:[0,1]→R$ does there exist a homeomorphism $h:[0,1]→[0,1]$ such that $f(h(x))$ is differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

As the title suggests: Under what conditions on a continuous function $f:[0,1]→R$ does there exist a homeomorphism $h:[0,1]→[0,1]$ such that $f(h(x))$ is differentiable?

Comment: I think a *sufficient* condition is: $[0,1]=\bigcup_n I_n$ where each $I_n$ is a closed interval and $f|_{I_n}$ is either constant or strictly increasing or strictly decreasing.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  That condition will get you a continuously differentiable function provided $f$ also has bounded variation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Four of my friends come immediately to mind.  The first two:

> Bruckner, A. M.; Goffman, C. Differentiability through change of
> variables. Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 61 (1976), no. 2, 235–241 (1977).

*...from the Math Review of this paper:*

> The authors prove two theorems in this paper. Suppose that $f$ is a
> real-valued function defined on the closed interval $[0,1]=I$.
>
> Theorem 1: There is a homeomorphism $h$ of $I$ onto $I$ such that
> $f∘h$ is differentiable on I and $(f∘h)′$ is bounded on $I$ if and
> only if $f$ is continuous and of bounded variation.
>
> Definition: A point $x$ in $I$ is called a point of *varying
> monotonicity* of $f$ if there is no open interval $J$ containing $x$
> such that either $f$ is constant on $I∩J$ or strictly monotone on
> $I∩J$. Let $k(f)$ denote the set of points of varying monotonicity of
> $f$.
>
> Theorem 2: There is a homeomorphism $h$ of $I$ onto $I$ such that
> $f∘h$ is continuously differentiable if and only if $f$ is continuous
> and of bounded variation, and $f[k(f)]$ has Lebesgue measure zero.
>
> Reviewed by H. E. White Jr.

That takes care of part of the problem.  Note that the first theorem produces a bounded derivative and the second a continuous derivative.  If you want simply a derivative consult this paper, which is a supplement to the Bruckner-Goffman paper.  Jim Foran and Dick Fleissner at the time communicated this to Andy and Cas and they encouraged them to publish it, even though it is a very short note.

> Fleissner, Richard J.; Foran, James A note on differentiable
> functions. Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 69 (1978), no. 1, 56.

*from the Math Review of this paper ...*

> Let $f$ be a real-valued function defined on an interval $I$. The
> authors prove that there exists a homeomorphism $h$ of $I$ onto itself
> such that $f∘h$ is differentiable if and only if $f$ is continuous and
> VBG*. This theorem complements results of the reviewer and C. Goffman
> [same Proc. 61 (1976), no. 2, 235–241; MR0432831].
>
> Reviewed by A. M. Bruckner

---

They key technical thing you would want to know before trying for any of this is this lemma:

Lemma.  Let  $Z\subset [0,1]$ be any measure zero set of type $\cal G_\delta$.  Then there is an absolutely continuous function $G$ defined on $[0,1]$ such that $G'(x)=+\infty $ on $Z$ and $1 \leq G'(x)<\infty$ on $[0,1]\setminus Z$.

This lemma is due (independently ) to Choquet and Zahorski from around 1940.

The most accessible reference (apart from the orginal papers) for this problem and indeed for anything you might care to know about derivatives is Andy's monograph.  See Chapter 9 for a full account and proof of this result of Bruckner-Goffman.

[https://www.amazon.com/Differentiation-Real-Functions-Crm-Monograph/dp/0821869906](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821869906)

---

---

**Addendum:**

The underlying idea is not that elusive.   If $f$ is a continuous function that you wish to transform by a *everywhere differentiable* homeomorphism $h$  to a differentiable function $f\circ h$ then you would certainly want to consider the same computation you did as a calculus student:
$$
\frac{(f\circ h)(y) - (f\circ h)(x)}{y-x}=\frac{(f\circ h)(y) - (f\circ h)(x)}{h(y) -   h(x)}
\frac{h(y) -   h(x)}{y-x} \tag{1}
$$

If both of the fractions on the right have a limit as $y\to x$ then, as every calculus student will tell you, the derivative of $f\circ h$ at a point $x$ is  $f'(h(x))h'(x)$.  If $f'$ fails to exist at $h(x)$ just arrange that $h'(x)=0$ at those points and that the fraction
$$\frac{(f\circ h)(y) - (f\circ h)(x)}{h(y) -   h(x)}
$$
is bounded.  In that case the limit in equation (1) is zero so the derivative is zero.

This works perfectly for Lipshitz funtions $f$.  Such a function fails to be differentiable at a set of measure zero and you need only tailor your homeomorphism to have a zero derivative at the appropriate measure zero set.  If $f$ is continuous and bounded variation it can be transformed into a Lipschitz function by a change of variables.

There are details to work through but that is the general idea here.